# Why value in pointer not incrementing when I use increment operator

Tags: c++, pointers

`int a=5; int *p=&a;`
I want to increment the value of a so I tried below two methods but why they are giving different values

why `a=*(p)++;` is giving 5
but `a=*(p)+1;` is giving 6

Comment: Can you try this line "a = (*p)++;"  to see what happens ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 That will give `5` since C++17 as well and has undefined behavior before that.

Comment: `*(p)++` is equivalent (due to different precedence of operators) to `*(p++)` not to `(*p)++`.     Since `++` is the post increment, the `*` is applied to the original value of `p`, not the value obtained after incrementing `p`.   So `a = *(p)++` gives the same effect as `a = *p;  ++p;`  whereas you are expecting it to give the same effect as `++p; a = *p`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `a=*(p)++;` the `()` around `p` don't do anything and the line is parsed as `a = (*(p++));` since postfix increment has higher precedence than indirection.

So you are incrementing the pointer, not the variable that the pointer points to. The postfix increment results in the value of the pointer before it was incremented, which you then dereference to give you the current value of `a`.

Then the line effectively becomes `a = a;`, doing nothing, except that `p` now points one-past `a`.

---

The line `a=*(p)+1;` is parsed as `a = ((*p) + 1);` since indirection has higher precedence than addition. This is effectively `a = a + 1;`, doing what you want.

---

There is however no point in using assignment at all. Just write `(*p)++;` to increment `a` through the pointer.